Issue Creating Google Meet When Creating New GCal Event
We have an application that imports our application's events into GCal and we recently attempted to add a google meet to that event to that same event.
conferenceDataVersion is set to 1, as specified in the documentation.
The response we get is a successful one and the event is created, the status of the conference is pending, however the google meet is never added to the event.
Any ideas?
Here is the code adding the conferenceRequest:
$conferenceRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
$conferenceRequest->setRequestId(Str::random(10));

$solutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
$solutionKey->setType('hangoutsMeet');
$conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey($solutionKey);

$conferenceData = new ConferenceData([
    'createRequest' => $conferenceRequest,
]);

$GoogleServiceCalendarEvent->setConferenceData($conferenceData);


Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. I understand you're trying to add a Google Meet link while creating a calendar event, and although I'm not well-versed in PHP, it seems like the parameters being provided are correct. The latest I found on Google's Issue Tracker related to this is Cannot create Google Meet link when inserting an event. However, on your end, The response we get is a successful one and the event is created, the status of the conference is pending, however the google meet is never added to the event.

Since I'm not seeing any open tickets that are specific to this, I recommend that you submit a bug report to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on. You may also try following the answer in this Stack Overflow post, which talks about how one can update a created event to add a Google Meet link. The only downside is that the language being used is Python.

This Stack Overflow post is likely related to what you're using, PHP. However, I believe that you're already familiar with it since I see that you've commented on the answer.
